# Improper Addition of array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [15] => Due
            [50] => Due
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [20] => Cancelled
            [30] => Due
        )

)
```

I want to display addition of the due amount on the parent array basis in the tabular format, like this:

```
Orders  DueAmount
  0       65     
  1       95
```

The code that I have tried:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Orders</th>
            <th>DueAmount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $tot = 0;
        for ($i=0; $i < count($ar); $i++) { // $ar is the parent array
            foreach ($ar[$i] as $key => $value) {
                if ($value === "Due") {
                    $amt = $tot += $key;
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$amt."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code when executed, gives the output as:

```
Orders  DueAmount
  0       15
  0       65
  1       95
```

How do I solve this ? Kindly help me out.

**UPDATE 1**:

After vascowhile's comment: I get the following output

```
Orders  Due Amount
  0       15
  0       50
  1       30
```

Comment: 65, 95 -- where do they come from?

Comment: `$tot = 0;` should be inside your foreach loop. I should add that I don't think it is a good idea to use array keys as values that way. What happens in the future if you need to change to decimal values?

Comment: When I run the above code, it gives me the output in that way.. They get added to previous value..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the echo'ing part out of your foreach loop :

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($ar); $i++) { // $ar is the parent array
    foreach ($ar[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === "Due") {
            $amt = $tot += $key;
        }
     }
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$amt."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.. Your Solution helped me.. Can you please help me out with this solution also ? Check the **UPDATE 2** of the question.. Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870664/cannot-add-array-values-whats-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Let's say this is your array:

```
$ar = array(
    array ( 
        15 => 'Due', 
        50 => 'Due' ),
    array ( 
        20 => 'Cancelled', 
        30 => 'Due' )
);
```

I modified your markup to this:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Orders</th>
            <th>DueAmount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        // This variable will handle the due's
        $due = 0;

        foreach ($ar as $row_number => $data) {
            // I used the main key of your array as row counter, or if you don't trust this
            // you can just declare a counter outside the foreach 
            // and increment here. This will solve your first bug.
            $row_number++;
            foreach ($data as $amount => $header) {
                // Same as your logic, accumulate the due in a variable.
                // This will solve your second problem. 
                if ($header == 'Due') {
                    $due += $amount;   
                }
            }
            echo '<tr>';
                echo "<td>{$row_number}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$due}</td>";
            echo '<tr>';
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```